# How to Know records updated with Update query?

Tags: mysql, c

How to know whether any record in the table updated with the update query or not.

I am using the Mysql C API..i have tried storing the mysql result after firing the UPDATE query but result is always returning NULL for successful upation also. Any help would be great.

Thanks

```
 int main(void)                                                                                       
{                                                                                                    
  MYSQL *conn;                                                                                       
  MYSQL_RES *res;
  MYSQL_ROW row;

  if ((conn = mysql_init(NULL)) == NULL)                                                             
  {                                                                                                  
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not init DB\n");                                                 
    return EXIT_FAILURE;                                                                             
  }                                                                                                  
  if (mysql_real_connect(conn, "localhost", "root", "password", "cpaas", 0, NULL, 0) == NULL)             
  {                                                                                                  
    fprintf(stderr, "DB Connection Error\n");                                                        
    return EXIT_FAILURE;                                                                             
  }                                                                                                  
  if (mysql_query(conn, "update calldirection set callid='Hello' where callid='He'") != 0)                   
  {                                                                                                  
    fprintf(stderr, "Query Failure\n");                                                              
    return EXIT_FAILURE;                                                                             
  }
  res = mysql_store_result(conn);

  if(res == NULL){
    printf("dssdg");
    return 1;
  }
  if ((row = mysql_num_rows(res)) <= 0)
        {
                printf("FFFFFFF");
        }


  mysql_close(conn);                                                                                 
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;                                                                               
}
```

Comment: You can explicitly store information about what was updated when and by who - but otherwise you're stuck

Answer (score 2):

After Doing Some R&D nearly for 1 day...I found **mysql_affected_rows(*mysql)** function which will return the number of rows updated for the UPDATE query.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [MySQL mysql-store-resul](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-store-result.html)

> After invoking mysql_query() or mysql_real_query(), **you must call
>   mysql_store_result() or mysql_use_result() for every statement that
>   successfully produces a result set (SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN,
>   CHECK TABLE, and so forth)**. You must also call mysql_free_result()
>   after you are done with the result set.
>
> You need not call mysql_store_result() or mysql_use_result() for other
>   statements, but it does not do any harm or cause any notable
>   performance degradation if you call mysql_store_result() in all cases.
>   You can detect whether the statement has a result set by checking
>   whether mysql_store_result() returns a nonzero value (more about this
>   later)

`mysql_store_result` returns `NULL` for the queries other than `(SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN, CHECK TABLE)` query types.

and `Update` query is not one of them, thus `mysql_store_result` returns NULL for it.

Comment: so you are saying that ..no way i can get the desired result for this question